# Most accurate programs to find similar music?

Tags: music

I'd like to find new pieces of music, resembling titles or a specific artist that I input into/specify for the program. [The excessive choice of programs](http://inspiredm.com/20-fantastic-ways-to-find-new-music-that-you-like-no-lastfm-pandora-inside/) claiming this ability mystifies me. Which ones are most accurate, reliable, or trustworthy?

**Update Nov 9 2014:** **OS:** The app can operate online or on Windows, but other OS are fine.

**Budget:** Please prioritise free, online services, rather than paid ones.

**What features must the application have?** This program should offer several recommendations at once, unlike Grooveshark that does so one at a time. Indicia/indicators of the recommendations' aptness and relevance are preferred, but not necessary.

**What sources to evaluate? What kind of output format?** Alas, I don't know what sources would be used by such programs. Any readable output format is fine, so that I can research these pieces, but a text format would be ideal for saving suggestions onto the PC.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially include your requirements. Linking to additional information is fine, but shouldn't require us to follow-up just to understand what you're asking for :) Should the app run locally? On which OS? What sources to evaluate? What kind of output format?

Comment: While "most accurate" is still pretty much subjective (unless someone really "knows them all"), I guess we just don't put the focus too heavy on that part and nominate it for re-opening, as the requirements are now pointed out.

Comment: AFAIK since last.fm stopped their radio there is *no* "track resembling this track" service. Artists yes.